# C calculation not operating as expected

Tags: c

Hi there I am currently trying to create a simple game in c based around a map with different ai players.

I've came along to program the calculations to figure out an amount of health lost and although I am sure my math behind it is correct the implemtnation in c doesn't seem to be working! I might have missed a simple point but I'll put the extract of code which isn't working as expected.

```
random1 = Numbergen(50);
cal1 = (100 - random1)/100;
random2 = Numbergen(50);
cal2 = (100 - random2) / 100;
PtrPlayer[attacker].health = (double)(PtrPlayer[attacker].health * cal1);
PtrPlayer[ncount].health = (double)(PtrPlayer[ncount].health * cal2);
printf("There was a battle but both players drawed and retreated.\n");
return 1;
```

Numbergen is a function that calculates a random number based on a time seed, 50 is the maximum number I want it to return with.

cal1 and 2 should store a decimal number for example 0.75 to take off 25% health and that's what the cal calculations should be doing however when debugging they are showing a value of zero no matter what the random number is.

This should work by taking the random number lets say 25 way from 100 to leave 75, it then divides by 100 to get a decimal multiplier which can then be used to reduce the health by 25%. Health starts at 100 so for example it will result in 100*0.75 which should leave me with 75 health but instead cal one stores 0 and as a result the health goes down to zero.

To be clear cal1 and 2 are both floats to allow for decimal places.

If anyone can point out where I might have gone wrong I will be so grateful! 
If I've missed out something important then please let me know and I'll try and explain.

Also please note I am only a beginner in programming so please don't hit me with super complex code!

As requested random1 and 2 are both ints
PtrPlayer[].health is set as ints
cal1 and 2 are set as floats

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the types of your variables ? This looks like an integer division issue.

Comment: Even if `cal1/2` are floats, if the whole `(100 - random1)/100` expression involves integers, it will still do integer division, truncating the fractional part. It's impossible to tell because you don't specify what type `random1/2` is.

Comment: `(100 - random1)/100;` --> `(float)(100 - random1)/100;`

Comment: added variables at the bottom.
Surely because I am casting it shouldn't have any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cal1 = (100 - random1)/100;
```

Since `random1` is an `int`, and `100` is an `int`, `(100 - random1)` is also an `int`. When you use the `/` operator on two integer operands, a truncating integer division is performed.

If you want floating-point division, convert at least one side of `/` to a floating-point type :

```
cal1 = (100 - random1) / 100.0f;
//         float literal ^^^^^^
```

... or...

```
cal1 = (float)(100 - random1) / 100;
```

Simply converting the result of the division would have no effect, as C expressions' types are determined strictly from the inside out.

Comment: Just ran it again doing (float)(100 - random1)/100; instead and its worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing either of the two 100 as 100.0

```
100.0 - random1

100.0 - random2
```

Or

```
(100 - random1)/100.0

(100 - random2)/100.0
```

This is the easiest option.